# Why can't I kill -9 this process?

Tags: linux, process, kill

A moment ago I tried to fill all space in a USB drive by typing `yes > a` to create a very large file and overwrite the old (sensitive) data.

But then, when the file grew to 4GB I got this error, and the `yes` process became unkillable:

```
yes: standard output: File too large
```

I attempted to kill the `yes > a` command with `Ctrl+C` and `kill -9` but both failed (`Ctrl+C` didn't do anything, `kill -9` returned with code `0` but didn't kill the process):

```
~ $ ps -fea | grep yes
my_user  8193  8084  1 09:58 pts/2    00:00:13 yes
my_user  9928  9847  0 10:20 pts/6    00:00:00 grep yes
~ $ kill -9 8193
~ $ ps -fea | grep yes
my_user  8193  8084  1 09:58 pts/2    00:00:13 yes
my_user  9939  9847  0 10:20 pts/6    00:00:00 grep yes
```

You can see the `kill` command returned, but `ps` continued showing the process (and the console that was running `yes > a` continued to be blocked).

After some 10 minutes the process finally finished. But why did the `kill -9` not work?

### Some more info:

- *USB filesystem:* vfat
- *Linux version:* Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: [Research material](https://stackoverflow.com/a/767571/10765659).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't use `top` to see if it had the `D` in it, but it looks like that was the issue: waiting on an uninterruptible IO request.